Returning the raw pointer from a list of unique pointers
I have a class (A) that will own the memory for a set of instances of another class (B). A will store its instances of B as a set of std::unique_ptr<B>.
I want A to be able to return a reference to a set of raw pointers to those B objects, (i.e. I don't want any transfer of ownership). What is the best way to do this?
class A
{
private:
    std::set<std::unique_ptr<B>> _Bs;
public:
    std::set<B*>& getBs() { ???? };
}

I could create a new vector:
class A
{
private:
    std::set<std::unique_ptr<B>> _Bs;
    std::set<B*>                 _rawBs;
public:
    std::set<B*>& getBs() { return _rawBs; };
}

std::set<B*>
A::A()
{
    std::transform(_Bs.begin(), 
                   _Bs.end(), 
                   std::inserter(_rawBs, _rawBs.begin()), 
                   [](auto uniq_ptr) { uniq_ptr.get(); }
    
}

But it seems a bit janky to store these pointers twice...

How about returning cosnt std::set<std::unique_ptr<B>> &? This isn't an ownership transfer.

I'm surprised std::set of std::unique_ptr even works.  What does the comparison operator do?

@MarkRansom Probably the same thing std::less does for raw pointers.

I would just return a const & for the existing set. If the user wants a copy, they can make one themselves. As a side note, I don't even understand the usefulness of a set here...

@MarkRansom https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_cmp

@SirXanderRoss "it seems a bit janky to store these pointers twice..." - why not just return a new std::set by value instead of by reference? Then you don't have to generate the 2nd set unless someone asks for it. If you store the set as a class member, then you have to keep it up-to-date if you ever modify the original set. That being said, are you sure you actually want std::set and not std::vector?

@RemyLebeau you can't return any container of std::unique_ptr by value.  Thanks for the link though.

@MarkRansom I was referring to the case of returning a set<B*> of raw pointers. That can be returned by value, and generated on-demand instead of in the constructor.

Why use a set at all?  I think a vector would be a better container.

You should add a member function:
const std::set<std::unique_ptr<B>>& getBs() {
    return m_bs;
}

There are a few things to note:

Unfortunately you cannot return something like std::span and have to return a reference to a const std::set. This leaks more implementation details, but is necessary because sets aren't contiguous containers.

You can still return a std::vector<B*> that contains a copy of all the pointers, but this would be more expensive.

A const std::set only lets you access the elements inside as const std::unique_ptr, so no ownership is being transferred, despite exposing the std::unique_ptr. Transfer of ownership would also require the ability to modify the std::unique_ptr.

You should not use the name _Bs for a data member because an underscore followed by a capital letter makes for a reserved identifier. See What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?.
The most popular naming scheme for members (if you give them a prefix or suffix) is the prefix m_.




I want A to be able to return a reference to a set of raw pointers to those B objects

That's a bad plan. What do you do if a caller modifies that set?
You could instead return a view of pointers, by value.
class A
{
private:
    std::set<std::unique_ptr<B>> Bs;
public:
    auto getBs() const { 
        return Bs | std::views::transform([](auto & ptr){ return ptr.get(); }); 
    };
};

If your std::unique_ptr<B>s are guaranteed to be non-null, you could instead return a view of references by swapping the ptr.get() for *ptr.
